# Can I concatenate these words using '-'?

Tags: hyphens, compounds

Can I replace *the hybrid of **table-oriented database and object-oriented** database approaches* by *the hybrid of **table- and object-oriented** database approaches*? Why and if not, how?

In addition, where can I find the documentation of such an usage?

Comment: You can unless there is no separate 'table database' which is different than 'table oriented'.

Comment: "Table database" seems don't exist semantically.

Comment: Then, you can use it. However, don't use the hyphen **after** the word 'table' (like this - *table-* as you have it in your question). So, it should go like - *"....of table and object-oriented database..."*

Comment: @MaulikV With all my due respect, I've seen several times that hyphens are used at the end of a single word and before "and" in English writing books.

Comment: Then I think it should work as an adjective with hyphens. Say - "He was often described as *'Kind-and-handsome'* by his female friends". Or it'd be better if you provide me with some example

Comment: @MaulikV I saw a case just now: "The pre-test, post-test, control, two-group-quasi- experimental design was used for this study." in the paper titled *The Influence of Process Approach on English as Second Language Students’ Performances in Essay Writing*. Please check it.

Comment: @MaulikV Here is another one: [Self-, peer-, and teacher-assessments in Japanese university EFL writing classrooms](http://ltj.sagepub.com/content/26/1/075.abstract)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I replace the hybrid of **table-oriented** database and **object-oriented** database approaches by the hybrid of **table- and object-oriented database approaches?**

**Probably not, but it depends on the context.**

Forgive me, but I am not sure if you've made a typo here. I think you meant to write "table-and-object-oriented databases" (notice the hyphen connecting "and" and "object"), just based on the question title. Otherwise, what you have currently written is equivalent to your original sentence for indicating both table-oriented database approaches and object-oriented database approaches.

As a compound adjective, that's tricky, because as a fellow programmer, it sounds like you're describing a specific database approach that is both table-oriented *and* object-oriented. In other words, a **table-and-object-oriented database approach.** This is different from the original meaning in your question, which refers to a **group of database approaches that includes both table-oriented approaches and object-oriented approaches.**

If you meant to say that all of the approaches exhibit both properties, then you should hyphenate as "table-and-object-oriented." If you wanted to say that there are both table-oriented and object-oriented approaches which remain separate but in the same group, then what you've written in the OP is fine. You can shorten your sentences in the way you've shown if they contain multiple compound adjectives with this technique, if they all use the same last word in their compound structure. For example, table-oriented and object-oriented both end with "-oriented," so you can say "table- and object-oriented" to mean "table-oriented and object-oriented." Again, different from linking them both in the **same** compound adjective.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. What I originally wanted to express is the [object-relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you suggest is probably technically correct, but it does look a little confusing.

What I would do is the first time you use the terms, write *table-oriented database (TOD) and object-oriented database (OOD)* and from then on just refer to them as *TOD* and *OOD*.